# Triggering a Macro (Specifics Required)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to trigger a Macro to run only in the row that the cell is triggered. It is an part of an approval process. When the user selects "A" from the drop down list, I want the corresponding number to be copied to another spreadsheet with a form on it. The issue is that it does not need to run for every cell in the column that has "A" in it. Only the one just changed to "A". Is this even possible?

Column with Drop Down List is point of approval for user.

Upon selecting A from the drop down, the corresponding number from Column X needs to be copied to another Worksheet.

[image]

[VBasic2008 - Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJARr.png)

Comment: Look into [Worksheet_Change Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change).

Comment: Replace the picture of code with text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1571407

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Worksheet Change: Change One Column and Write From Another Column to Another Worksheet

- Column `M` is showing the order in which the `A`-s were written to column `N`.

[image]
[image]

**Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1**

```vb
Option Explicit

' This event is triggered by any manual change in the worksheet i.e.
' writing a value to a cell (e.g. Range("N4")), copy-pasting values
' to multiple contiguous cells i.e. a range (e.g. Range("L5:P10")), and doing
' the same by using VBA which additionally can write
' to a non-contiguous range (e.g. Range("A1,N4,C7")).
' All these cells (or only one) that are being written to at the same time
' are referenced by 'Target'.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Source
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "N4"
    Const sColumn As String = "X"
    Const sCriteria As String = "A"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dColumn As String = "A"
    
    ' Reference the range of interest, the source range.
    Dim srg As Range
    With Me.Range(sFirstCellAddress)
        Set srg = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
        ' i.e. 'N4:N1048576', or 'N4:N65536' for prior Office 2007
    End With
    
    ' Use 'Intersect' to reference only the cells of the source range.
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(srg, Target)
    
    ' Check if there are no source range cells contained in 'Target'
    ' and exit if true.
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Status: There are cells (at least one) from the source range
    ' contained in 'Target'.
     
    ' Reference the destination worksheet and the last occupied cell
    ' in the destination column ('dColumn').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Me.Parent.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dColumn).End(xlUp)
     
    Dim iCell As Range
    
    ' Loop through all the cells referenced by 'irg'.
    For Each iCell In irg.Cells
        ' Check if the current intersecting cell is equal to the criteria.
        If StrComp(CStr(iCell.Value), sCriteria, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ' Reference the cell below the last occupied destination cell.
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
            ' Write the value from the cell in the source column in the same
            ' row as the current intersecting cell ('iCell'),
            ' to the destination cell.
            dCell.Value = iCell.EntireRow.Columns(sColumn).Value
            ' or the equivalent which may be more understandable at this stage:
            'dCell.Value = Me.Cells(iCell.Row, sColumn).Value
        'Else ' is not equal to the criteria; do nothing
        End If
    Next iCell
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain this one? I have entered in my source as the Sheet name, the second sheet needs to fill in on column E

Comment: Ok it's still not triggering, what did I miss here? @vbasic2008 edit in post

Comment: The only thing you needed to change is the values of the constants `dName` and `dColumn`. Leave the rest of the code intact. Also, you have to copy the code to the module of the worksheet whose screenshot you have posted.

Comment: this still isn't working. I added a pic with the changes noted out to the side. I am sure I am missing something just not sure what.......

Comment: Ok I re-read your instructions and now I am getting a debug error on this portion 
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Me.Parent.Worksheets(dName)                            
the portion you told me to change is done                                                                                        
    Const dName As String = "Raw Material Dispsosal Form"
    Const dColumn As String = "E"

Comment: Ok I re-read your instructions and now I am getting a debug error on this portion 
    <Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Me.Parent.Worksheets(dName)>                            
the portion you told me to change is done                                                                                        
    <Const dName As String = "Raw Material Dispsosal Form">
    <Const dColumn As String = "E">

Comment: *Dispsosal* is usually written as `Disposal`, without the middle `s`. Is the code in the sheet module of the worksheet in the screenshot? Irrelevant, but if you have accidentally disabled events, in a new sub use the line `Application.EnableEvents = True` and run it.

Comment: I changed the spelling thank you for pointing that out. I also have this in the "tracker" sheet module. I also ran the other enable events code in both the sheet module, and regular module. I added a current pic of what I have to the post for reference

Comment: Eureka!! It is working!! Not sure what happened but it's working!! Thank you so much!! @vbasic2008

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Docs has the exact documentation found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/run-macro-cells-change

Using the sub Private Sub Worksheet_Change(), you can execute code when any worksheet values are changed. Additionally, you can parse in a specific range and then run a conditional such as

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range : Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    
    MsgBox ("Cells have changed in the Keycells range!")
    'Do Code here....
    'Conditional statement to check if the range = "A"
    
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI `Range(Target.Address)` in a worksheet code module is the same as `Target`, and using this syntax with a large multi-area (non-contiguous) range can silently "clip off" part of the range if the length of  `Address` gets too large...